# Как удалить кавычки из элемента в списке Python

Tags: python, list

Имеется список с несколькими списками в каждом из которых есть несколько элементов

```
['"Designator3_1_1_1_3_2', 'Comment', 'TopLayer', '2835_LED(TP)', '64,0200', '-94,7500', '180', '', '64,2500', '-94,7500', '63,0000', '-94,7500"']
['"Designator4_1_1_1_3_2', 'Comment', 'TopLayer', '2835_LED(TP)', '76,5200', '-94,7500', '180', '', '76,7500', '-94,7500', '75,5000', '-94,7500"']
['"Designator2_5_2_3_2', 'Comment', 'TopLayer', '2835_LED(TP)', '64,4800', '-82,2500', '360', '', '64,2500', '-82,2500', '65,5000', '-82,2500"']
['"Designator1_5_2_3_2', 'Comment', 'TopLayer', '2835_LED(TP)', '76,9800', '-82,2500', '360', '', '76,7500', '-82,2500', '78,0000', '-82,2500"']
```

Перед первым и после последнего элемента в списках стоят двойные скобки и мне нужно их убрать. Я вывожу эти списки циклом `for`

Дополнение:
словари импоритруются из CSV файла

```
import csv
spisok = ('')
spisok = list(spisok)
with open('Pick Place for CMEM_V01.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        for spisok in row:
            print(spisok)
```

Comment: только это не скобки, а кавычки

Comment: ну суть в том что их нужно убрать оттуда

Comment: добавьте replace('"', '') прямо в код, где формируете словарь

Comment: @Jack_oS словарь формируется прочтением CSV файла так что я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: добавьте код "прочтения CSV" в вопрос

Comment: @Jack_oS добавил

Comment: Вам ещё и числа из строк в просто числа наверное придётся преобразовывать

Answer (score 1):

по каждому элементу просто делайте

```
replace('"', '')
```

и все

```
for obj in arr:
    for elem in obj:
        print(elem.replace('"', ''))
```

если же надо изменить сам список, то:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr[i])):
        arr[i][j] = arr[i][j].replace('"', '')
```

Comment: Я пробовал, у меня за пределами цикла список никак не меняется

Comment: Даниил Радченко, у меня код был для вывода на экран, если менять список, то надо конечно было по индексам идти - сейчас добавлю такой код