# Как удалить кавычки при экспорте csv из python

Tags: python, csv, форматирование

При экспорте таблицы в нормальном виде

```
['VD3', 'LED_3030', '28.7550', '64.1000', '', '', '', '', 'T', '180', 'LED_SMD']
['VD2', 'LED_3030', '47.3050', '64.0400', '', '', '', '', 'T', '180', 'LED_SMD']
['VD1', 'LED_3030', '28.7550', '64.1000', '', '', '', '', 'T', '270', 'LED_SMD']
```

В конечном файле вещественные числа берутся в кавычки и получается

```
VD3,LED_3030,"28.7550","64.1000",,,,,T,180,LED_SMD
VD2,LED_3030,"47.3050","64.0400",,,,,T,180,LED_SMD
VD1,LED_3030,"13.5000","52.7150",,,,,T,270,LED_SMD
```

Эти кавычки нужно убрать. Вот код экспорта

```
with open('{}'.format(filename)+'.csv', "w", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(lest)
```

Забыл уточнить что код экспорта получает таблицу уже в правильном виде, тоесть он сам добавляет эти кавычки

Comment: replace же, вам [сегодня давали ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1241795/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-python)

Comment: @Jack_oS Извиняюсь забыл уточнить один момент, я в конце вопроса добавил пояснение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить кавычки из элемента в списке Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1241795/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-python)

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как всё записать, надо убрать эти кавычки с помощью команды `float()`
В результате у вас должен поменяться **код** примерно вот так:

```
with open('{}'.format(filename)+'.csv', "w", newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for x in range(0,len(lest)):
        try:
            lest[x] = float(lest[x])
        except:
            print(lest[x],'не получаеться преобразовать в число')
        writer.writerow(lest[x])
```

[Детальнее можете прочитать здесь](https://andreyex.ru/yazyk-programmirovaniya-python/uchebnik-po-python-3/python-3-strokovaya-funkciya-replace/)

Comment: Всё не так просто так как код экспорта получает таблицу в правильном виде то есть в том который я скинул первым блоком кода, извиняюсь что не уточнил

Comment: Ето строка а не числа, просто переобразуйте строку в `float( string )` исправил*

Comment: Нуу, как вам? Помогло ли?

Comment: Нууу, чево не отвечаете?

Comment: я попробовал, мне выдаёт ошибку о том что я пытаюсь пустую строку преобразовать

Comment: Ну тогда загоните это в try except а точнее Вот так
`try: string = float(string) except: print()` изменил ответ*

Answer (score 0):

Я для себя нашел решение, но не уверен что оно самое подходящее, можно ли сократить количество действий?

```
lest = ['VD3', 'LED_3030', '28,7550', '64,1000', '', '', '', '', 'T', '180', 'LED_SMD']

for value in lest:  #Element iteration
    for sim in value:   #Symbol iteration
        if sim == ',':
            index = lest.index(value)
            value = list(value)
            value.insert(value.index(sim), '.')
            value.remove(',')
            value = ''.join(value)
            lest.pop(index)
            lest.append(value)
            lest.insert(index, value)
            lest.pop()

print(lest)
```

Результат

```
['VD3', 'LED_3030', '28.7550', '64.1000', '', '', '', '', 'T', '180', 'LED_SMD']
```

Comment: @Jack_oS да, вместо запятых стоят точки

Comment: lest = [e.replace(',', '.') for e in lest]

Comment: у вас вопрос про кавычки, ответ - про запятые...